# Двусвязный список на низком уровне: вставка элемента за константное время

Tags: c, сложность, двусвязный-список

На уровне аллокатора памяти требуется реализовать двусвязный список.

Сперва выделяется память уже готовым аллокатором - именно она в дальнейшем используется для списка.

В самое начало кладутся метаданные: размер, указатели на первый и последний блоки и прочая информация. После метаданных сохраняются сами элементы списка.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
1) Как производить вставку нового элемента за O(1)? Как я понимаю, разумнее всего связать свободные блоки в односвязный список и сохранить указатель на первый элемент в метаданных. Но, к сожалению, непонятно, как это реализовать на техническом уровне. Вернее, вариант есть, но, кажется, он имеет недостатки и можно проще.

К примеру, существует такая структура:

```c
struct free_el {
   free_el *next;
}
```

Она добавляется в начало каждого блока, а после производится инициализация `next` - указателя на следующий подобный блок.

В этом подходе заметны две проблемы: линейная сложность инициализации и размер блоков, которые могут быть меньше 4 байт в случае `x86` и меньше 8 байт в случае с `x64_86`. Если первое - не так проблемно, потому что не оказывает влияния на время выделения, то последнее - фатальный недостаток, нарушающий работу алгоритма (размер адреса структуры будет больше размера элемента списка из-за чего указатели будут испорчены, а сохранение последнего и вовсе повлечет выход за границы памяти).

2) Очевидно, что участок памяти, выделенный ранее, конечен. То есть рано или поздно понадобится дополнительная память. Как объединить / связать второй участок с первым, сохранив при этом константную сложность выделения и возможность освободить эту память, если все блоки списка окажутся свободны?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну соединить то не проблема. как и любые списки. Просто выставить в последний элемент первого списка в качестве next первый элемент второго списка.

Comment: Предлагаете так же произвести инициализацию второго участка памяти, а после сохранить указатель на первый элемент в метаданные первого? Тогда все-таки неясно, как освободить второй при необходимости, и, если возможность все-таки найдется, все адреса структуры `free_el` будут вести к памяти, которая больше не принадлежит аллокатору

Answer (score 1):

Вообще не понимаю о чём тут написано но вот: Первое о чём думаешь, почему бы не хранить адрес предыдущего блока , в односвязных только так удаляют :/
Если список всё же двусвязный то нельзя ли во время соединения поставить в графе Next первого участка адрес второго участка, а в графе Prev второго участка поставить NULL. В этом случае двигаться до упора мы сможем лишь в одну сторону, а двигаться в обратную сторону мы сможем лишь до конца участка. Ужс, специфичные будут функции... Пока других идей нет)

Comment: Попробую развернуть второй вопрос. Смотрите, сперва программе предоставляют один участок памяти - в нем хранятся метаданные и сами элементы списка. Через время список заполняется и свободное место заканчивается, соответственно, нужно выделить дополнительную память. И вот на этом этапе появляются вопросы. Нужно ли что-то хранить в начале второго участка памяти? Если да, то что? В общем, нужно организовать схему взаимодействия первого участка со вторым так, чтобы сложность вставки осталось константной и его - второй участок - можно было освободить, если все ячейки в нем свободны